# Reading https web page data behind proxy java

Tags: java, proxy, https

I want to read a secure webpage data say https://www.paypal.com, i am behind proxy. I tried with

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
System.setProperty("htttps.proxyHost","myproxyhost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","443");

URL u = new URL("https://www.paypal.com");
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);

StringBuffer sbuf=new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));

String res = in.readLine();
System.out.println(" Response from paypal "+res);
while ((res = in.readLine()) != null){
       sbuf.append(res).append(",");
}
in.close();

System.out.println(" Total Data received  "+sbuf);
```

i am getting UnknownHostException all the time, I am successfully fetching data with http websites. Am i missing something?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 4):

You've got 3 T's in your `proxyHost` settings, i.e. you are using `htttps` rather than `https`.